# multiple overrides with Bloomberg API

Tags: overriding, bloomberg

It seems Bloomberg API can only override with same overridevalues for a list of bonds. for instance, to override Yield with Price, I can only use the SAME price value for a list of different bonds.  My problem is: how to override Yield with different Price values for EACH different bonds. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general (and not only for bonds), when using overrides, you are passing the same set of overrides for all the securities/dates of the request. If you want to use a different set of overrides for different securities you need to send multiple requests, each with different overrides. Note that the overrides are added directly to the request object.

When I encountered a similar issue I grouped the securities I was requesting data for by the overrides. I sent one request for each distinct set of overrides.

Comment: Thank you for confirming no possibility with one single request for multiple overrides.